# is it possible to take screen shot from video like as in VLC player?

Tags: android, screenshot

I have developed an application in android which contains videos. Now I want to take screenshots from that running videos.
I tried with `SurfaceView` and `Bitmap` classes:

```
Bitmap image = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
```

But it's not working. How can I get a screenshot of the running video?

Comment: post your code and try to explain what is not working.

Comment: i m getting height and width of surface view when i pause video..and create Bitmap and set into Imageview but its not give any image....

Comment: How are creating the bitmap? post that code snippet

Comment: did you find any solution?